# Spring Boot Rest API with Microsoft Azure AD

Tags: spring, azure, authentication

I have a Rest API developed with Spring Boot and neo4j as a database. There is no Frontend in the Spring Boot App. It only serves as a Backend. The Frontend is developed in Flutter.
In my app, the end user has to sign up and login with theis user credentials. The user management is currently handled with Spring Security and JWT, generating and storing the tokens with `AuthenticationProvider`, `UserDetailsService` and so on.

Now, we are migrating our whole infrastructure to Microsoft Azure. We already managed to get the DB, the Backend (as the Spring Boot App) and the Frontend there.

The question now is whether it makes sense to migrate the User Management to Azure Active Directory. Is this the right use case for that, or is Azure Active Directory actually there for other use cases?
Also, I want to use my Login and Signup Forms built with Flutter. I only found solutions so far where you get redirected to this Microsoft Login Form. I want to signup/login directly from my Flutter App, and then use the token for my requests in the Spring Boot App.

Does this even make sense? If yes, how can I realize that? I was searching for hours but I didn't find any proper solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use AAD you will have to use the OAuth redirect based Microsoft login experience. There is no way around that.

If you can't think of any way you or your users will benefit by migrating to AAD, then there's no reason to do that. You're doing a bunch of work, and incurring risk, for no real benefit.